# Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, php-5.4

While clearing the cache error are came.

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in** `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php` **on line 104**

**logs created below**

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Page
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Page_Head
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Page_Notices
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Page_Header
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Page_Menu
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Notification_Baseurl
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Cache_Notifications
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Notification_Survey
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Notification_Security
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Widget_Breadcrumbs
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Page_Footer
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Notification_Toolbar
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Notification_Window
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tabs
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View_Messages
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View_Items
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_Payment
Easylife_Pickup_Block_Sales_Order_View_History
..........................
.............................
etc..
```

I don't know why it's came Can any one suggest me?

how can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From looking at **Action.php** line 104 is contained within this function:

    /**
     * Define active menu item in menu block
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
        return $this;
    }

So it would appear that something is wrong with **$this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')** have you modified the layout.xml or the menu?

Comment: @Dave, I just clear the cache manually `var/cache` and disable my module. now working. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your answer and accept it to close this post?

Answer (score 4):

This was an issue with cached functions from an extension that had been removed. Manually clearing the cache fixed the issue.

Manually clear the cache using one of the following methods:

- Use standard method `Mage::app()->cleanCache()` or `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();`
- Use n98-magerun to clear the cache from the shell. (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)
- Manually delete the var/cache directory (if file cache)
- Clear relevant db/redis/memcache cache

Additionally sometimes apc or opcode cache can cause issues, and restarting php may be required in those cases.